# Validar While php

Tags: php

Cordial Saludo

Tengo un problema para poder validar los registros que me trae una bd por while.

Tengo el siguiente while que funciona perfecto

```
 while( $row_tree = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt_tree, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row_tree['NOM_PRODUCTO'];
    }
```

Pero necesito que cada 4 registros, haga algo, es decir, los primeros 4 registros que trae el while, va a meterlos dentro de un div con x clase y los proximos cuatro, de cuatro en cuatro, los mete en otro div

Comment: Añade un conteo que sume uno por cada registro y haces un `$conteo % 4` para ver si tienes que cambiar de div...

Answer (score 1):

La mejor opcion seria haciendo uso de [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-chunk.php) para ello lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
$row_tree = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt_tree, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

$row_splited = array_chunk($row_tree, 4,TRUE);
```

con esto te deberia quedar un arreglo de la siguiente manera

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0]=>Array(),
        [1]=>Array(),
        [2]=>Array(),
        [3]=>Array(),
    ),
    ...
    [n] => Array(
        [0]=>Array(),
        [1]=>Array(),
        [2]=>Array(),
        [3]=>Array(),
    )
)
```